# Plotting netCDF data with folium - python

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections, folium, wgs84

I have a netCDF file which contains only `x_orig` and `y_orig` in LCC format(*i.e. no latitudes, longitudes for each data value*). I was able to correctly convert it to `(lat, long)` pair to plot them over Google Maps - where the projection I used is `wgs84 (outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326'))`.

Next I wrote functions to find out every `lat` and `long` for the grid. But even, that seems to a bit skewed.

**The idea is:**

I could produce the correct concentration plot using Basemap's contourf where the image created is in LCC projection. I save this image on my device.

And then use folium's feature of `ImageOverlay`; where I mention the boundaries i.e.(`max_lat, max_lon, min_lat, min_lon`). But the image is incorrectly aligned. Is this because folium uses `epsg:3857`?

How do I overcome this challenge?

*(i.e. producing an interactive map which correctly displays my data in LCC projection)*

Comment: What do you mean by 'incorrectly aligned'?

Comment: Here is an example: 
~~~   _let this be the boundary of a country on the folium map_
        ~~~   _then this the boundary of the same country on the basemap image _

now, these two curves must overlap i.e. I must align the image perfectly over the folium map. Equivalent to superimposing the basemap_created_image over folium_map @Yuca